# How confident can I be that this distribution is random (or not random)?

Tags: probability, distributions, descriptive-statistics

Here's my background and hypothesis: I have a list of 1000 items, and I choose 100 of them (without replacement).  Then I replace the 100 chosen items and repeat this test many times.  If the items are selected in a way that all items are equally likely to be chosen, then the distribution of the selected items should be uniform, right?

If there is some doubt that the method of selecting the 100 out of 1000 items is NOT uniformly random, how can I measure how close or far it is from being uniformly random?

Below is a picture of this distribution.  In the picture, there are 100 items selected 31 times out of a list of 1033.

[image: Distribution of random selection from a set]

That is how I would describe the problem without being specific to my application.  What I'm really trying to do is test the randomness of Spotify.  So the list of 1000 items is my saved songs (actually 10033), and the 100 selected is the list of songs that are put in the queue when you push "shuffle play" on all liked songs.

Comment: Hypothesis testing and measuring how far something is from something else are fairly different ideas. What do you want to do?

Comment: The number of times each song is selected has a binomial distribution with parameters $31$ and $1033$.  The $1033$ numbers you observe are not independent, but they are almost independent so you may as well treat them as if they are.  So compare the $1033$ numbers with what you might expect from the binomial distribution.  For example you might expect about $49.1$ songs to be selected exactly six times and about $18.8$ to be selected seven times - unless you have cut off the top of the bar chart, that is not what you have

Comment: @Henry is correct.  You can experiment with the `R` command `table(table(replicate(31, sample.int(1033, 100))))`, which lists the frequencies of each count.  For instance, the first time I ran this I found 54 items were sampled 6 times, 16 were sampled 7 times, and 10 were sampled 8 or more times.  Upon doing this exercise 10,000 times, the average number of items sampled 6 times was $49.02\pm0.063,$ agreeing with Henry's result.